# How implement Notification system in PHP and Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I Have a Laravel based application, I want to add a notification system like Instagram and other social networks. how I should implement the Database and PHP to achieve this goal?! (I just want the base knowledge about implementing this functionality, not the code)

for example: when someone does some action about your profile: a new notification send to you and you noticed that for example "John created a new Deal with you".

Comment: This isn't really the type of question suited to Stackoverflow. It is mostly opinion based. There is an entire section of the Laravel documentation dedicated to notifications https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/notifications You should start there.

Comment: Basically: Using Javascript and AJAX, the page must check every 5 seconds or so a database change in your server. Good luck with that.

Comment: @Amarnasan my question is how the database should look like?! I should create a new table for example called the "notification" and connect it to the model with one to one relationship, or not?! what is the base implementation of this?! I hope that my question is clear

Answer (score 1):

there are dozen of push notification libraries and also server side programs you can use. they support web notifications also.

and if you want to create your own notification system (for any reason) the story differs. but recommended way is to use those libraries and not to bother yourself!

i think there should be two notification system type: static and dynamic.
in static system you save each message for user and whenever he logged in you show him all messages. you can utilize session for saving and manipulating messages.

in dynamic way, like a stream based way, you just save the time user saw the messages last time and when user logged in you will make the messages dynamically and show him those.